# Output Nested Handlebar helpers that exist in the data

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am coming up against a wall and not seeing how I can loop over handlebar helpers that are found in the provided data. 
I adjusted a jsfiddle to illustrate what I'm looking to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

You will see that the `{{position.one}}` in the data is equal to the string `Team Lead` which I can output without a problem, but when that helper is used inside `{{person.jobTitle}}`, it just outputs `Front End {{position.one}}`.

Is there a way to have this output the `{{position.one}}` that is in the `{{person.jobTitle}}` so that the output is `Front End Team Lead`?

Here is the fiddle. Thanks for taking a look!

http://jsfiddle.net/z9u5jz7w/1/

*Re: @luciano-santos*
Trying to find a way to loop over everything regardless if the expression is standalone or the data contains another expression.

I found this library  extension (https://github.com/mateusmaso/handlebars.nested), but only seems to work if the expression is directly in the expression being evaluated ie `{{jobTitle {{position.one}} }}` instead of the `{{jobTitle}}` actually containing the `{{position.one}}` expression.

Seems like I may need to write something to evaluate if the expression contains `{{` and re-evaluate.

**Answer**

Ended up writing a custom helper for this. Hopefully it helps someone else as well. This helper allows evaluation of nested expressions found in JSON or your given dataset.

https://github.com/davidwickman/handlebars-helper-inception

Comment: i don't think you can render templates from data, without some kind of custom handler...

Answer (score 1):

Ended up writing a custom helper for this. Hopefully it helps someone else as well. This helper allows evaluation of nested expressions found in JSON or your given dataset.

https://github.com/davidwickman/handlebars-helper-inception

Answer (score 0):

In handlebars, the expression cannot contain other expressions. You'd better prepare your data before sending to Handlebars, like you did to the name:

```
var data = { 
    users: [ { 
        person: {
            firstName: "Garry", 
            lastName: "Finch"
        },
        job: {
            title: "Front End",
            position: "Team Lead"
        },
        twitter: "gazraa" 
    } ]
};
```

This way, you can create a helper, like you did to the person's name, and concat both values.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('fullJob', function(job) {
  return job.title + " " + job.position;
});
```